# predicate builder with two tables

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, predicatebuilder

[image]

A *Party* can have one or more *Contact* objects.

I want to select all *Parties* who's streetname contains a specific keyword.
If I just want to search in *Party* I can use the code below. But how do I extend it to also search in *Contact*?

```
public IQueryable<Party> SearchParties(List<string> keywords)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Party>();

        foreach (string word in keywords)
        {
            var keyword = word;
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.surname.Contains(keyword));
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.lastname.Contains(keyword));
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.number.Contains(keyword));
        }
        return db.Parties.Where(predicate);
    }
```

Is there anything else you need to know?

**EDIT**
I guess I could create another predicate and then join them afterwards. Something like:

```
var predicate2 = PredicateBuilder.False<Contact>();
```

...and in the foreach:

```
predicate2 = predicate2.Or(p => p.streetname.Contains(keyword));
```

But how would I join predicate and predicate2 before returning?

**EDIT2**
Or, join the *Party* and *Contact* before doing the predicate Builder?

**EDIT3**
Here are parts of the generated classes:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Contact")]
public partial class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _id;  
    // ...more properties  
    private EntityRef<Party> _Party;

    public Contact()
    {
    this._Party = default(EntityRef<Party>);
    OnCreated();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that you have multiple Contacts to a single Party, hence you should decide if you want to have a Party if "any of the Contacts match the street name" or "all of the Contacts match the street name".

For the first case it would be:

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contacts.Any(c => c.streetname.Contains(keyword))));
```

Comment: Thanks! You just waited until I posted a bounty on it, didn't you =)

Comment: I didn't see your question before. I guess the bounty brought it up to the top of the stack. ;)

Comment: <resurrect> what if there's no explicit relationship between the tables? i.e. no foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your model has Contact as an associated object on the party object (and if it doesn't have a one-to-many relation)

```
predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contact.streetname.Contains(keyword));
```

Comment: Tried that but I guess I don't =/. How do I add it as an associated object?

Comment: What ORM are you using e.g. Linq to sql,  EF

Comment: Linq to SQL, I started of with the NerdDinner.

Comment: When you generate your datacontext for linq to sql from the database if the party and contact table have a foreign key relationship it should associate it for you.  You could try refreshing the context from the database.

Comment: Didn't work. I do have `public EntitySet<Contact> Contacts` that I guess maps to Party with the foreign key. So I thought I'd search that set instead: `predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contacts.Where(c => c.streetname.Contains(keyword))));` But it says it cannot implicitly convert to bool.

Comment: Could you post the Contact and Party Classes

Comment: The whole generated model is 2.2k rows. The classes are too big to post I think. But if I have an EntitySet Contacts instead of a single Object Contact. Shouldn't it be possible to specify the streetname anyway?

Comment: why don't you pass lambda expression instead of list<string> ?

Comment: @Stacker - What do you mean and will that help my question?